# Two properties, one type

Tags: json-ld

When author and publisher of an article are one and the same, with Microdata it’s possible to markup in the following manner:

```html
<span itemprop="author publisher" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
<span itemprop="name">Name of the Organization</span>
</span>
```

Is there another option other than the following when using JSON-LD?

```
"author" : {
  "@type" : "Organization",
  "name" : "Name of the Organization"
},
"publisher" : {
  "@type" : "Organization",
  "name" : "Name of the Organization"
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no equivalent functionality in JSON-LD. Depending on whether you have identifiers for your entities or not, you might be able to leverage reverse properties to achieve the same. Generally, however, I wouldn't advise to use such "hacks".

```
{
  "@context": [
    "http://schema.org/",
    { "publisherOf": { "@reverse": "publisher", "@type": "@id" } }
  ],
  "@id": "/book",
  "author" : {
    "@type" : "Organization",
    "name" : "Name of the Organization",
    "publisherOf": "/book"
  }
}
```

Comment: I thought perhaps this might be the case. Thank you very much for taking to time respond Markus, appreciate the help.